# Kernel of $xp(x)+p(0)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Having a bit trouble in finding the kernel of

$$L(p(x))=xp(x)+p(0)$$
where $p(x) \in P_2(\mathbb{R})$.

I thought of expanding it like

$$x(ax^2+bx+c)+p(0)$$

but this leads to 3rd degree polynomial whose roots are complicated.

Is this the only way?

Comment: Do you mean $L(p)$?

Comment: Note that the roots of $xp(x)+p(0)$ aren't important - you want the expression to be equal to $0$ *as a polynomial*, not just at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $p(x)$ is degree $d\ge1$, $xp(x)+p(0)$ is degree $(d+1)$, and so cannot be equal to the $0$ polynomial.

Furthermore, if $p$ is nontrivially degree $0$, i.e. a nonzero constant, then $xp(x)+p(0)$ is degree $1$, and again thus cannot be equal to the $0$ polynomial.

So, $p$ must be degree $0$, and cannot be equal to a nonzero constant, hence must be identically $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\forall x:\ x(ax^2+bx+c)+p(0) = 0\implies p(0) = 0.$$

Comment: Which implies $x=0$ is the only solution to $L(p(x))=0$?

Comment: @mavavilj $x=0$ is not a polynomial. Youre solving for $p$, not $x$.

Comment: @mavavilj, $\forall x:\ xp(x) = 0\implies p(x) = \cdots$

Comment: @mavavilj, $-c/x$ isn't a *polynomial*.

Answer (score 0):

If $L\colon P_2(\Bbb R) \to P_3(\Bbb R)$ and $p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$, we must solve $$L(p(x)) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+c = 0 \in P_3(\Bbb R)$$ for $p(x)$ and not for $x$, so this must be the zero polynomial. So immediately we must have $a=b=c=0$ and $L$ is injective.

If you fix $p(x) \in P_2(\Bbb R)$ and define $L\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by that expression, then you must solve the third degree equation.